# Dates overwrite as null on TextBox with TextMode="Date" on ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: date, model-view-controller, input, scaffolding

I got an ASP.NET WebForms Project with an Formview inside an UpdatePanel, and got a TextBox on the Edit Template binded to a SQL Database with the next code

```
<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("FechaEventoInicio") %>' runat="server" ID="FechaEventoInicioTextBox" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date"/>
```

and a Label on the item mode with this code

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("FechaEventoInicio", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' runat="server" ID="FechaEventoInicioLabel" CssClass="form-control" disabled="" />
```

The issue comes on the edit template, when I try to edit the date, the date seems to be overwrite by the control itself, i'm debbuging on chrome, but i tried on Edge and Firefox, and the problem is the same. Tried again on a Scaffolding form with MVC 5 and the same thing, i guess it's about the control on the browser, but my knowledge on this is very short. Thanks a lot for your answers.

PD: Thanks to Vincent for the advice on posting

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Vincent!